# Brushless motor driver fails at PWM duty > 10%

Tags: mosfet, brushless-dc-motor, mosfet-driver

I am trying to use an Allegro [AMT49413](http://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/Files/Datasheets/AMT49413-Datasheet.ashx) chip to driver a brushless motor.  The circuit kind of works with a PWM duty up to about 10% (if I give the motor a push first). But above 10%, the gates don't seem to be coming on properly.

[image: AMT49413 Brushless motor driver (not fully working)]

I have carefully checked every aspect of the design and build, and everything seems to be correct, but I still can't make any progress.

According to the datasheet, p13, the PWM duty can be limited by selecting too high a value for the bootstrap capacitors. However, I believe I have my calculations correct for the [SIR882](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1915698.pdf) MOSFETS I am using:

```
Cboot = Qgate x 20 / Vboot
      = 18.3nF x 20 / 13v
      = 28nF
```

I have also tried moving down to 18nF, and it didn't seem to affect the maximum PWM duty.

Other settings:

- Fosc       = 34kHz (from 1nF CT and 24k RT)
- Dead time  = 1.4us (from 100k Rdead)
- Blank time = 2us (from 1nF CT)
- External PWM = 31.25kHz

Any ideas what might be causing the problem, or what I can investigate next?

Added: The High side MOSFETS are also getting quite warm.

Comment: 28 nF sounds low. Please show Vgs oscillograms for low and high side MOSFET in one leg. Is there an internal diode for the boot on the driver?

Comment: why would a too big bootstrap cap limit the duty cycle? The charging delay they are talking about is only present at first chargup if im correct.

Comment: Voltage drop on bootstrap cap is QGtotal/Cboot. Datasheet states your voltage drop on bootstrap cap should be less than 400mV, yours is 2V at the moment. Bootstrap diode is internal (see p14)

Comment: @Jogitech - Just trying to get the oscillogram.  Do you think I should use a higher value Cboot? Does QGtotal mean 18.3nF x 6 ?

Comment: Hope there is no limit on consecutive comments. I just realized you used the wrong value for total gate charge. Your Vgs is 13V, datasheet states that Qgtotal is 58nC (max) at 10V Vgs. You should use the maximum value from the datasheet in this matter.

Comment: QGtotal is the total gate capacitance of one FET. why 18,3nF* 6? You have 3 high side FETs and 3 bootstrap caps respectively. Also gate charge is not measured in Farads. Considering the datasheet of the fet and the Controller your bootstrap cap must be at least 58nC/400mV=145nF, i would simply use 220nF

Comment: @Jogitech - Whoops, I meant to write 18.3nC.  Sorry, I didn't understand what you meant by 'total' gate charge. I thought you meant the total gate charge for the whole board (for all 6 MOSFETS).  Now I understand that the gate charge I should use in the calculation isn't the one mentioned at the top of the datasheet, but the one in the table lower down.

Comment: About the hot high side fets: could be caused by the small bootstrap caps too. You have pretty big gate resistors (is there a reason?) which results in the fet turning on very slowly, due to the additional lower voltage available to turnon the high side fets (caused by the small bootstraß cap) they are most likely staying in an area with high RdsON longer than the low side.

Comment: @Jogitech - The datasheet recommends gate resistors, but doesn't suggest a value.

Comment: I suggest you use smaller gate resistors because in this configuration you spend almost 15% of one switching period to fully turn on/off your fets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly what is going on without probing around  the hardware, but perhaps some of these ideas might help:

1. You're pulling up the hall inputs through an LED.  This might be fine, but seems a little non-standard.  Have you checked the voltage levels and the transition times on those inputs?  The VIH is 2V I believe for those inputs - you should make sure you have a bit of margin - unknown how much current your off-board hall sensors can sink.  VIL is 0.8V, so if your hall sensors are having difficulty getting that signal low enough, it might cause the problems you're describing.
2. You mentioned that your high side fets are getting warm.  Have you looked at the gate drive waveforms?  These can be tough to look at.  Sometimes I'll put one scope channel on the bridge output (fet source), another channel on the gate voltage, both referenced to ground.  Then you can do a math function and subtract one from the other to get a good gate-source representation on your scope.  Then you can look at voltage levels and make sure you're above your gate-source threshold.  Also look at transition times to make sure that the drive is healthy.  If those things are good, then you can rule out any issues with your bootstrap capacitance, charge pump, internal diode, etc.
3. Your gate-drive resistors seem large.  I would back these down to 1 ohm or 10 ohms until you can isolate / optimize this part of the design.  Get it working first - this could make the design not work, and would cause your upper FETs to spend too long in a transition region and get warm.
4. I would get rid of your output capacitance - i.e. C12 / C13, C16/C17, C14/C15.  Perhaps add them back in later if they help with noise mitigation, but if you think about it, every time you sequence a motor phase, you have to charge / discharge these caps.  The current pulses are probably huge to charge them up when the FETs come on.  On the order of amps.
5. (EDIT) One last thing.  You added bypass capacitance for Vbb, which is good.  However, you grounded your caps above the sense resistor.  You should instead bypass to your power ground.  You want the IC to "see" all the current through the motor phases.  It appears that with the way you've got it wired, any current that passes through the circuit from the large bypass caps will not get sensed by the IC appropriately.

Let us know how it turns out!

Comment: Looks like the output capacitance was causing a lot of the problems.  I wonder why the datasheet recommends them?

Answer (score 1):

What / whoever told you you should use a huge low Zc(f) electrolytic cap across a +/-5 PWM with 1 milliohm RdsOn and cap ~1 Ohm ESR (est.)

Ic= C dV/dt  will be huge.

This is an AC short circuit condition for a 3 phase DC bridge driver,  limited by ESR of the Caps.

Remove these and use twisted pairs to motor directly for each phase.  Shielded cables and ferrite balun also help reduce EMI.

**Put 3 low ESR e-Caps across the "VBB-LSS" DC supply+return rails very close to each (3) MOSFET pair instead.**  Use only low ESR caps 1~10uF with 10m~20m Ohm ESR  ( similar ESR to RdsOn of FETs, although best designs will use C values similar to uH value of motor coil for low inductance, low DCR motors

Comment: That's what I thought. However, it does say that in the datasheet. Bizarre!

Comment: Read again. I am correct.  "VBB. Decouple with at least a 100 nF ceramic capacitor mounted
between the VBB pin and the AGND pin. A larger electrolytic
capacitor, typically 10 µF, in parallel with the ceramic capacitor
is also recommended."  See Fig 3  ( more Bizarre that you would accept a contradiction to basic electronics training :)

Comment: Read again: Page 16: "Consider the use of small (100 nF) ceramic decoupling capacitors **across the source and drain** of the power FETs to limit fast transient voltage spikes caused by trace inductance"

Comment: I had a hard time reading the units. Sorry I saw uF but upon zooming it is nF. My fault.  The issue here is minimize dead time on the load inductance (?? H) so that during dead time   current goes into the cap and clamp diodes rather than the inductive trace and load.  BTW what is your load L,DCR?   Dead time which becomes "dt" ought to be < 1us and the spike peak as dV = L*dI/dt approx. Adding a small series R to the load also reduces L/R =T value.

Comment: My experience on Rg is that Rg/DCR_load 100~1000 depending on shaping of dead-time.

Answer (score 1):

Ok to sum it up:

Calculation of Bootstrap Capacitors: Datasheet states that the voltage drop on the bootstrap cap shall not be more than 400mV; Total Gate Charge of MOSFET is approximately 60nC considering your Gate to Source voltage. The minimum required bootstrap cap is therefore

CBoot_min = 60nC/400mV --> 150nF --> use 220nF

Adjust Gate resistances: High Gate resistance results in long transitions times of the FETS which has a positive effect considering EMI but a negative effect on power loss of the FET (long VDS/ID overlap), also you waste a long time switching (appr. 1us with your config). Considering the deadtime of 1.4us you might even have crossconduction. I suggest you go with a gate resistor below 10 Ohm.

Hot high side fets: Probably a combination of long transition times (possible crossconduction) and the probably lower VGS voltage of the high side fets.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the Cboots to 220nF, and the gate resistance to 10R.  It's hard to say if those were definitely among the problems, but probably were. The last problem was the output caps. When I removed those, it worked nicely.